# C++ Clearing streams, and testing input - multiple issues

Tags: c++, validation, input, stream

I'm currently learning C++ in class, and I have 3 problems with validation.  My professor asked me to not user stringstream for validating input.  I'm running into a problem where if the user enters two characters 'rr' for example, the error message displays twice (Which is why I just used stringstream originally to test for the first incorrect character). The second problem is if they enter two values, such as  -45 -56.  Somehow, the second value of 56 is coming to be positive after the loop and the program is running with it, even after I cleared the stream.
Lastly, if a user enters a float into an int, it truncates it - but how do I prevent that from happening?  E.g. I only want an int entered.  I tried less than and greater then with no avail. Notice in the below posted code, I do not have the truncating problem because the user input is a double - but I think someone should understand the theory of what I'm asking.

Please let me know if the formatting on here is not correct, I was having some issues with pasting it in the block, but it looks like it may be alright now.

Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main()

{
const double EARTH_G = 1, SPACE_G = 0, EARTH_MOON_G = .17, VENUS_G = .90, MARS_G = .38,
    MERCURY_G = .38, JUPITER_G = 2.36, SATURN_G = .92, URANUS_G = .89,
    NEPTUNE_G = 1.14, PLUTO_G = .07;

double userWeight;

enum planets {Earth = 1, Space, Moon, Venus, Mars, Mercury, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus,
Neptune, Pluto};


/*Validates input by making sure checking for only numbers greater than 0*/
{
    bool flag = 0;
    while (flag == 0)
    {
        cout << "What is your earth weight in lbs?" << endl;
        cin >> userWeight;
        if (!static_cast<double>(userWeight) || userWeight < 0)
        {
            cout << "Invalid Input.\nPlease enter only positive numbers." << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();


        }
        else
        {
            flag = 1;
        }

        }
    }
{
    //Displays menu with choices, and allows produces output based on choice.
    //Loops while input is invalid.
    bool flag = 0;
    int choice;
    double newWeight;
    while (flag == 0)
    {
        cout << "Select a place in space with a number to see your weight there!\n\n";
        cout << "1  - Earth\n\n2  - Space\n\n3  - Earth's Moon\n\n4  - Venus\n\n5  - Mars\n\n"
             << "6  - Mercury\n\n7  - Jupiter\n\n8  - Saturn\n\n9  - Uranus\n\n10 - Neptune\n\n11 - Pluto\n\n";
        cout << "Select 1 - 11:\n";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case(Earth):
        {
            newWeight = (userWeight * EARTH_G);
            cout << "Your weight on earth is " << fixed << setprecision(1)
                 << newWeight << endl;
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        case(Space):
        {
            newWeight = (userWeight * SPACE_G);
            cout << "Your weight in space is " << fixed << setprecision(1)
                << newWeight << endl;
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        case(Moon):
        {
            newWeight = (userWeight * EARTH_MOON_G);
            cout << "Your weight on the Earth's moon is " << fixed << setprecision(1)
                 << newWeight << endl;
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        case(Venus):
        {
            newWeight = (userWeight * VENUS_G);
            cout << "Your weight on Venus is " << fixed << setprecision(1) << newWeight << endl;
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        case(Mars):
        {
            newWeight = (userWeight * MARS_G);
            cout << "Your weight on Mars is " << fixed << setprecision(1) << newWeight << endl;
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        case(Mercury):
        {
            newWeight = (userWeight * MERCURY_G);
            cout << "Your weight on Mercury is " << fixed << setprecision(1) << newWeight << endl;
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        case(Jupiter):
        {
            newWeight = (userWeight * JUPITER_G);
            cout << "Your weight on Jupiter is " << fixed << setprecision(1) << newWeight << endl;
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        case(Saturn):
        {
            newWeight = (userWeight * SATURN_G);
            cout << "Your weight on Saturn is " << fixed << setprecision(1) << newWeight << endl;
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        case(Uranus):
        {
            newWeight = (userWeight * URANUS_G);
            cout << "Your weight on Uranus is " << fixed << setprecision(1) << newWeight << endl;
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        case(Neptune):
        {
            newWeight = (userWeight * NEPTUNE_G);
            cout << "Your weight on Neptune is " << fixed << setprecision(1) << newWeight << endl;
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        case(Pluto):
        {
            newWeight = (userWeight * PLUTO_G);
            cout << "Your weight on Pluto is " << fixed << setprecision(1) << newWeight << endl;
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? I would imagine if you have enough knowledge to downvote, you could provide a quick answer?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did run though the debugger and the results I posted in my questions were what I saw.  Am I to build a table of variables and post it?  Or just rewrite a single example of code? The code posted is the minimal amount needed to see my problems with the exception of the truncation problem that I clearly stated was not in the code, but he theory is simple to understand.

Comment: Sorry, on phone and couldn't scroll to edit. I have researched quite a bit, debugged and all my research keeps saying to use stringstream, but my professor says not to use.  Hence, I am asking here as a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore , the basic, no parameters `ignore` only removes one character from the input stream. According to the example provided in the above documentation link, the recommended usage is

```
input.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

To consume the entire line. Note the additional include statement required to get `numeric_limits::max`.

Comment: Thank you! Something i was just completely overlooking.